# using jquery serialize in ajax operation for plugin

Tags: plugins, ajax

I am writing a plugin with dynamic no. of input fields in form. To submit form via ajax, I have used jquery serialize() function.

```
$(".submit").submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = {
            action: 'wpaie_ajax_action',
            operation: 'import',
            importData: $(this).serialize()
//do some operation
        };
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

        });
    });
```

Ajax is working fine and data is also serialized but I am not able understand how to read the form input fields.

If I am using `echo $_POST["importData"]`, it is showing me serialized data but what should
be the correct way to read that serialized data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that your server receives data in the form of a string which it should if you're using the jQuery serialize() function.

It will be something like:

`name1=value&name2=value&name3=value`

You just need to parse the string into an array as follows:

`$parameters = array();
parse_str($_GET, $parameters);`

See the following for more information: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: Thanks for the help!!! I will use parse-str to parse the values. Thanks